# remove quote of a string to make it as expression

Tags: r, expression, eval, quote

I want to pass a formula to a function, but I can not remove the double quote from the string of the formula. How could I do it? Thanks.

```
clust_start=c(1,100)
i <- 1 
Lambexp <- 1:99
rank <- 1:99
alpha <- 1:99
d <- 1
b <- 1:2
ww=as.matrix(c(1:99), nrow=99)
expression.logdens <- paste(Lambexp[rank[(clust_start[i]:(clust_start[i + 1] - 1))]],         
"*exp(", alpha[(clust_start[i]:(clust_start[i + 1] - 1))], " + bb*", ww[(clust_start[i]:    
(clust_start[i + 1] - 1)), d], " - ", b[d]*ww[(clust_start[i]:(clust_start[i + 1] - 1)),     
d], ")", sep="")  

expr.formula <- paste(expression.logdens, sep="", collapse=" + ")
```

I tried expr.formula <- as.expression(expr.formula) and as.name(expr.formula), they didn't work.

```
logdens <- function(bb){
    y <- expr.formula    
        return(y)
    }
logdens(1)
```

Comment: @joran Yes. I don't want to pass the whole logdens function to c function arms() in HI, it's too slow. So I just want pass the calculated result to arms().

Comment: Define "slow," and maybe we can advise as to whether alternative methods would be faster in the first place.

Comment: BTW,  ignoring the other problems, take a look at `call` and `do.call`

Comment: If you want a string `x` be converted into an `expression` without the quotes use `parse(text = x) `as jbaum says (the result will be `eval`able). If you want something else, give a better explanation or example.

Comment: I rolled back your edits. Editing your question to clarify/expand on it is fine, but it should remain the _same_ question, otherwise the answers it has already received look like nonsense. If you have a new, different question, feel free to ask that separately.

Comment: @joran Thanks. I will post the new question.

Answer (score 4):

You want this:

```
logdens <- function(bb){
  eval(parse(text=expr.formula))
}
```

Output:

```
> logdens(1)
[1] 1.539673e+45
```

Comment: It's does work. I need to pase this logdens function to arms() in package HI, so I can not use eval(), bb will the samples from arms(). Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as `as.formula(expr.formula)` ... once you fix your formula to be actually valid ;)